# iPhone iOS how to programmatically check for characters like ✭ ♦ (and others from this set)?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, ascii, nscharacterset

I know that both ✭star and ♦ diamond are from the ASCII extended character set. But is there some NScharacterSet available on iOS that I can use to check for characters like these programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

you can display these symbols using charsets `ISO 8859-1 or UTF-8.`

```
 [ ★ ] star solid [ number: &#9733;]


 [ ♦ ] black diamond suit [name: &diams;] [number: &#9830;]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the NSString object method: rangeOfCharacterFromSet. It returns NSRange object.

From that,

Eg.:

```
NSCharacterSet *charSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"] invertedSet];

NSString *string = @"Stach✭Overflow";

NSRange range = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet];
if(range.location != NSNotFound) {
// one of those characters is exists in the string.
}else{
//no specifiedcharacter not found.
}
```